# How to see if any item in a list is inside a string in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to check if any item in a list is in a certain string in Python. Specifically for a Discord bot using Discord.py.

```py
if list(open("file.txt")) in message.content.lower():
        # do stuff
```

Specifically, I want my bot to do something once it finds an item in a list in a message a user has sent. I already have what I want it to do programmed, but it's the detection I'm having problems with.

What I had originally tried to do is:

```py
if any(list(open("file.txt"))) in message.content.lower():
        # do stuff
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Projects\Python\gssbot\env\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 409, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "e:\Projects\Python\gssbot\main.py", line 35, in on_message
    if any(list(open("file.txt"))) in message.content.lower():
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not bool
```

Can anybody help me with what I'm trying to do? I've looked for answers of what to do multiple times and haven't found anything that suits my need.

P.S. I only want its commands to be called once, even if there are multiple item occurrences in a message.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing this backwards; if you want to check is any of the lines of the file exist in the message content, you want:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:  # Use with statement for guaranteed reliable file closing
    message_content = message.content.lower()  # Avoid repeated work, convert to lowercase up front
    if any(line.rstrip("\n") in message_content for line in f):
        # do stuff
```

That generator expression reads a line at a time from the file, strips off the newline, and checks if the rest is somewhere in the lowercase message content, producing a stream of `True`s and `False`s. As soon as a single truthy value is seen, `any` exits with a result of `True` (without wasting time checking the rest of the file), if it never sees a truthy value, it returns `False`.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure this is because you are trying to find a **bool** ("Any" function returns you *True* or *False*) in a **string**, which is impossible.

You can do it like this for example, but I am sure there are some more effective and faster solutions.

```
OK = True
for item in list(open("file.txt"))):
    if item not in message.content.lower():
        OK = False
if OK:
    # your code
```

Comment: There is almost never a good reason to do `for x in list(anything):` (barring the off-chance `anything` is mutable and you'd be changing it during the loop); here, it just means eagerly slurping the whole file into memory for no reason, iterating over the list, then throwing it away; removing the `list` wrapping would allow processing to begin immediately, and only require memory proportionate to the longest line, not the whole file. Also, your code is only leaving `OK` as `True` when *all* the items are in the message content; the OP seems to want to know if *any* of them are in it.